# Model change event: bind Region.show or View.render?

Tags: marionette

I have a model which i fetch from the server and then render the view. Should i bind a call to my regions's show method with model's change event?

```
  menuModel.bind("change" , function(){
            leftMenuRegion.show(leftMenu);
        });
        menuModel.fetch();
```

But then what happens when the model is fetched again?
Or should i for the first time fetch the model, call regions's show method and then bind view's render method to model's change event?

```
  menuModel.fetch(); 
  leftMenuRegion.show(leftMenu);     
  menuModel.bind("change" , function(){
                leftMenu.render();
   });
```

And also, please advice whether in such cases, is it at all possible/recommended to listen to model's change event at the time of instantiating view like below.

```
initialize : function() {
  this.bindTo(this.model, 'change', this.render, this);
},
```

Is it not inconsistent to render the view sometime through calling region's show and sometimes view's render? Please advice what should be the coding standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view shows the model, and should be the one listening to the "change" events. You can do so in the `initialize` method (in the view):

```
initialize : function() {
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
}
```

You only use the regions `show` method to indicate what view the region should show. You don't call that again unless you want to display a *different* view in that region.

To wait for the model data to be fetched before displaying the view, you can use a deferred, as explained here: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/ (note that `fetch` returns a deferred object, so you can use that value as your promise).

To have `render` be called only once, use a deferred to delay displaying the view in the region. Then, call `menuModel.fetch({ silent: true });` which will prevent the "change" event from being fired when teh data is received.

Comment: Thanks David. I meant to use deferred in the second option that i mentioned above. sorry for the confusion. But my point remains. I cannot bind to change event in my initialize code for view. Other wise the render will be called twice. Once due to fetch deferred calling region's show, and second due to change getting fired on model. Am i missing something?

Comment: I've udpated my answer. You can use the `silent: true` option to prevent the "change" event from being fired by `fetch`